# Intellij Invalid Gradle JVM Configuration

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

**Environment**:
Java version: 14.0.1
Gradle version: 6.4
Intellij version: 2020.1.1

I have a valid Java installation. I have set `JAVA_HOME` to point to the Java installation directory.
Everytime when I tried to start new project ( Gradle project ) in Intellij, I will always got an error like one in the picture.

Why Intellij keep using Gradle version 6.1? My Gradle installation is 6.4.
Due to this error, Intellij dont even create any Gradle files like `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat` or gradle folder

Here the error:

[image: Error]

Here the setting:

[image: Setting]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Image says that you don't have a `gradle-wrapper.properties` file. You should create `gradle` folder and `wrapper` folder inside it. In Wrapper folder you need two files `gradle-wrapper.properties` and `gradle-wrapper.jar`.

[Gradle website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

Comment: Intellij should have created all of those file for me

Comment: Should, but it didn't. Or it was deleted/moved after.

Comment: thats the problem, it should, but apparently it didnt..i come to conclusion there is bug with Intellij, currently it doesnt support gradle 6.4

Comment: it did work for you when u create new gradle project? i mean, u dont create the project through gradle and then open it with Intellij?

Comment: No, I didn't create new one, just change `distributionUrl` from old one

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error

```html
JDK 17.0.1 isn't compatible with Gradle 7.6. Please fix JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

I needed to change the JDK version project seting(on windows IntelliJ) : **File --> setting --> build tools --> gradle**

Screenshot with correct version, earlier it was pointing towards Java 11 [image: settings]

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue when you select JDK 14 version IDE will fail to create a project since used by default gradle wrapper version is not compatible with 14 JDK. The workaround is to use lower JDK for new project or use 6.3 Gradle version (specify it in IDE Gradle settings: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Use Gradle from**).

It will be fixed in next IDE update.

Comment: where to specify Gradle version in Intellij?

Comment: I have updated the answer - basically, this is the settings page of the screenshot you have posted :)

Answer (score 0):

I was making a Spring Boot application on Windows with Intellij and the project directory resides on WSL Ubuntu. And got a similar message.
`Found invalid Gradle JVM configuration: Platform SDK does not point to valid JDK (\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\usr\lib\jvm\java-8-openjdk-amd64)`

I ignored it and the program still ran.